# Upgrading drives in Netgear NAS box, model RNDX4000

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas

I have a Netgear [ReadyNAS NVX](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/RNDX4000%20(ReadyNAS%20NVX).aspx) with 4 x 500Gb (non-SSD) HHDs running on RAID5.

I'm running out of space, and want to increase the capacity of the box.

Is it possible... and if so, how do I do it?

I know that RAID 5 works on redundancy, and that if a disk crashes I should (in theory) be able to replace it without any loss of data.  So is it is feasible to replace each disk (one at a time, with new 2Tb drives) until all 4 are replaced?

Comment: Your plan is sound, but it will still give you only 500 GB initially and you'll have to grow the filesystem somehow. Have you checked the manual for any hints?

Comment: It's a bit tricky navigating through the manual online, and no I haven't found any hints yet.  Obviously most things are for replacing existing drives, not expanding the overall capacity of the box.  Not something I can really play with, as it's our primary backup at home

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Netgear Support Community](https://community.netgear.com/t5/New-ReadyNAS-Users-General/upgrade-capacity-of-RNDX4000/m-p/946459#M22676), do this one disk at a time, allowing the volume to complete a resync before upgrading the second disk. Also, suggest the drives you pick are on their Hardware Compatibility List.

[Hardware Manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/RNDU2000/ReadyNAS_Ultra_UltraPlus_NVX_Pro_HW_en_8July11.pdf)
[Hardware Compatibility List](https://kb.netgear.com/20641/ReadyNAS-Hard-Disk-Compatibility-List)
[Installation Guide](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/RNDU2000/RAIDiator_4.2_Desktop_IG_en_PRT_25July11.pdf)
[Software Manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/RNDU2000/ReadyNAS_Business_SW_05Nov13.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @K7AAY - it's much appreciated... although I'm rather scared about actually doing it!

Comment: Backup. Verify the backup. Backup again. Verify the second backup. Backup is your friend.

Comment: Indeed... a bit more difficult when the NAS **is** the backup!  I might invest in an external 2Gb HDD to take a copy, as well as the new internal HDD's for the NAS

Comment: Backup to cloud?

Comment: Could take a while, but yes definitely an option

Comment: You know how much your data is worth.... and, if this is the best answer which works, suggest you click the check mark at left which shows you approve it.